# solve negative values in a javascript based countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown, gettime

I am creating a countdown to count the time between a match of the euro2012 that I intend to watch.
I've come with a working version of it but I don't understand why it gives me sometimes negative values.
I think it has to do with the way I wrote it, using the getTime() method.
Here is my code, could you guys help me find out to solve those negative values?
Thank you very much in advance.

```
<body onload="timeto2012()">
<script type="text/javascript">
 function timeto2012() {
 var euro2012 = new Date(2012, 5, 10, 20, 45);
 var euro2012ms = euro2012.getTime();
var now = new Date();
var nowms = now.getTime();

var diff = euro2012ms - nowms;

var seconds = 1000;
var minutes = seconds*60;
var hours = minutes*60;
var days = hours*24;
var years = days*365;

var ddays = diff/days;
var dhours = (ddays - Math.round(ddays,1))*24;
var dminutes = (dhours - Math.round(dhours))*60;
var dseconds = (dminutes - Math.round(dminutes))*60;

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML='' + Math.round(ddays,1) +' days '+ Math.round(dhours,1) +' hours '+ Math.round(dminutes,1) +' minutes '+ Math.round(dseconds,1) + ' seconds remaining';

}

t=setInterval(timeto2012,500);

</script>   
<div id="time"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: You should accept the answers that were posted to you on previous answers.

Comment: Here's a fiddle to play with: http://jsfiddle.net/YHktx/1/

Comment: Aleksi, still showing negative seconds...

Comment: It wasn't an answer :) Correct seconds can be achieved using modulo but I'm trying to check why the seconds are displayed in range [-30,30]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KOGI has the answer to your problem: You should use `Math.floor` instead of `Math.round`:

When there's x minutes and 30 - 59 seconds left, the `(x - Math.round(x))` would be equivalent to `(x - (x + 1))` after the rounding was done.

```
var ddays = diff/days;
var dhours = (ddays - Math.floor(ddays))*24;
var dminutes = (dhours - Math.floor(dhours))*60;
var dseconds = (dminutes - Math.floor(dminutes))*60;
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YHktx/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here are some better calculations for you (derived from Aleksi Yrttiaho's jsFiddle)

```
var seconds = 1000;
var minutes = seconds*60;
var hours = minutes*60;
var days = hours*24;
var years = days*365;

var ddays = Math.floor( diff/days );
var dhours = Math.floor((diff % days) / hours );
var dminutes = Math.floor(((diff % days) % hours) / minutes );
var dseconds = Math.floor((((diff % days) % hours) % minutes) / seconds );
```